# How to attach download counter to download button?

Tags: php

I have 6 download buttons in a page for 6 different files. I want download counters for each of them. And the "NO OF TIMES DOWNLOADED:" for each file to be displayed under each file's picture on the webpage. 
http://www.aamaodisha.org/secdownload.html

I just amn't being able to move any further ahead. 
I have very limited knowledge about PHP but after searching a lot on Google, I stumbled upon a code for counting the no. of downloads:

```
<?php

$num= intval(file_get_contents('counter.txt'));
$num+=1;
file_put_contents('counter.txt', $num);

echo "No of times downloaded " . $num ." ". ;
?>
```

To see for myself, how it functions, I saved this php as downloadcounter.php and placed it in the download directory of my webhost where my original files to be downloaded are located. I also changed the download link to 
`<a href="Magazine/downloadcounter.php?number=1&file=9thEdition.rar>Download</a>` in my HTML for the first download button. 
I also placed a counter.txt file in the same download directory with initial value as 0 (i.e the notepad file named COUNTER.TXT has only 0 written).

But when I click my download button, though the file starts downloading (which means that I have successfully linked my download through the php file (downloadcounter.php)
But when I look into the counter.txt after each download, I still see 0

Can you please guide me as to how to show the number of downloads on my webpage under the DOWNLOAD button, the way i have planned as this http://www.aamaodisha.org/secdownload.html
On this HTML page, I have simply written the number of downloads, but they aren't the actual automatic counter generated data :( 
Can someone show me the way out? I have been stuck here on these download counter designs since two days. (I sincerely apologise for my limited knwoledge about PHP or other languages)

Thanks in advance

Comment: flat files like that are a bad idea.

Comment: I understand but I am really handicapped by my poor depth in PHP or other scripting languages :(

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use files for this. Locking will become an issue if two people download at once. Use MySQL, Redis.io, or really anything else...

If you must though, try this:

```
<?php
$num= intval(file_get_contents('counter.txt'));
$num+=1;
file_put_contents('counter.txt', $num);
```

Comment: You mean to say my php code should be like this:

`code`<?php
$num= intval(file_get_contents('counter.txt'));
$num+=1;
file_put_contents('counter.txt', $num);
echo "No of times downloaded " . $num ." ". ;
?>

Comment: That is correct. I still do suggest that you try out redis, it literally has no learning curve. (<---- slight exaggeration)